# move object with position absolute with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I keep the absolute location sub-navbar under the navbar?

Note: **position:fixed**  should not be because I encountered problems because it is on mobile, I am following such a way to fix it.

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll > 50) {
            jQuery('#navbar').css({position:'fixed'});
            jQuery('.sub-navbar').css({position:'absolute',top:'+=5'});
            jQuery('body').css('marginTop','60px');
        }
        else {
        jQuery('.sub-navbar').css({position:'absolute',top:'-=5'});
        }
  });
```

```css
body{
  height:1500px;
}
nav{
  background :#333;
  color:#FFF;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
}

#navbar{
  top:0;
  z-index:9999;
  
}
.sub-navbar{
  display:inline-block;
  background:#CCC;
  padding:20px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="navbar">
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>About</a>
  <a>SSQ</a>
  <a>Contact</a>
</nav>
<br>
<div class="sub-navbar">Sub Navbar</div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat harum ex dolor saepe culpa repellat velit facilis vel itaque labore.
</p>
<br>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat harum ex dolor saepe culpa repellat velit facilis vel itaque labore.
```

Thank you Advance.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you add class instead of adding css with jquery example

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll > 50) {
        jQuery('#navbar').addClass('scrollTop-nav');
        jQuery('.sub-navbar').addClass('scrollTop-subnav');
        jQuery('body').addClass('scrollTop-body');
    }else {
        jQuery('#navbar').removeClass('scrollTop-nav');
        jQuery('.sub-navbar').removeClass('scrollTop-subnav').addClass('scrollTop-subnav-new');
        jQuery('body').removeClass('scrollTop-body');
    }
});
```

```
#navbar.scrollTop-nav{
    ...
}

.sub-navbar.scrollTop-subnav{
    ...
}

body.scrollTop-body{
    ...
}

@media(max-width: 480px){
  ...
}
@media(min-width: 481px){
....
}
```

from there you just need to change the css with the class without bothering to use it